# Running a Spring Boot project with Quartz scheduler on Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, quartz-scheduler

I am working on a Spring Boot project which has a scheduler service using Quartz. This scheduler service runs a specific scheduled or cron job by calling a separate micro-service.

Now I am planning to deploy my micro-services on kubernetes and I want to make sure that my scheduler service is also clustered. I have noticed that Quartz s[upports clustering](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html) using JDBC-JobStore but I am not entirely sure if such a scenario can be deployed using kubernetes. Will it work if I have 3 pods of the Scheduler service managed and scaled using kubernetes?

Comment: As you will use Kubernetes you should have a look at Kubernetes Jobs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

Comment: Can these `cron-jobs` be compared to a scheduler like Quartz ? Schedulers usually have an administration interface to change schedules and they are extensible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes as long as you run the quartz in **Cluster Mode** and set **org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO** it does work.

In case of scaling, just some pods will be added or get removed, Quartz will take care of it since each instance would have its distinct instance ID.

Comment: What about @DisallowConcurrentExecution? Will that work?